# inline-block and float widths/wrapping behave differently?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to decide no the best way to make a side-by-side column-like layout using CSS and `div`s.

For some reason when I use `display: inline-block;`, if the aggregate width of the column-divs is equal to 100%, the last div wraps onto the next line.  However, if I use floating divs, this doesn't happen, even with identical width.

For example, the two divs in this example appear on different lines:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rleahy.ca/reset.css" />

        <style type="text/css">

            .column {   width: 50%;
                        display: inline-block;
                    }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="column">

            Column 1

        </div>

        <!--    This div is on the second line  -->
        <div class="column">

            Column 2

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

But in this example they don't:

```
<html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://rleahy.ca/reset.css" />

        <style type="text/css">

            .column {   width: 50%;
                        float: left;
                    }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="column">

            Column 1

        </div>

        <div class="column">

            Column 2

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Using both Chrome and IE8.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline-block respects white-space in your markup. try:

```
<div class="column">Column 1</div><div class="column">Column 2</div>
```

see what happens

Comment: Ya this works, but be aware that IE7 does not support inline-block.

Comment: In IE7 using this hack will make the element inline-block
.ie .col{display:inline;
zoom:1;}

Comment: Don't feel dumb, the simple fact is that no syntax should **ever** respect machanisms for increasing human readability. It is the fundamental flaw in the inline-block layout approach.